# End ssh connection via batch

Tags: batch-file, ssh

everybody,

i'm trying to write a batch which should install a certain firmware on a router. To do this, it is necessary to copy the firmware to the router and then the batch should dial into the router via SSH. That works so far everything. 
Afterwards I call the function which performs the firmware upgrade. But the function restarts the router at the end and the connection via SSH is not closed. This means that the batch window remains open the whole time. 
After the restart I want to upload a configuration. For this you have to connect to the router again. But I can't do this because the SSh connection stays open the whole time and I can't use a new command in the batch.

Question would be now:
How can I end the SSH tunnel, even though I am stuck in the function that should be loaded with the firmware?

Here are the functions I call with the command to update the firmware

`plink.exe -ssh root@192.168.1.1 -P 22 -pw admin sysupgrade /tmp/firmware.bin`

Output of the function. The batch stops at the following position

```
Collected errors:
 * file_sha256sum_alloc: Failed to open file /etc/quagga/bgpd.conf: No such file or directory.
 * file_sha256sum_alloc: Failed to open file /etc/quagga/ospfd.conf: No such file or directory.
 * file_sha256sum_alloc: Failed to open file /etc/quagga/ripd.conf: No such file or directory.
Saving config files...
killall: watchdog: no process killed
Sending TERM to remaining processes ... logd rms_connect rpcd logtrigger gsmd simd netifd eventslogd uhttpd mdcollectd port_event_chec dnsmasq crond ubusd askfirst statusledctrl mwan
Sending KILL to remaining processes ... mwan askfirst
Switching to ramdisk...
sh: 0: unknown operand
Performing system upgrade...
Unlocking firmware ...

Writing from <stdin> to firmware ...  [w]
```

Answer (score 0):

The router should close the server side session while restarting. On your batch window you should be able to exit the stuck process with a CTRL+C combination